# How to determine the continuity of a function in an interval?

Tags: python, math, sympy

is it possible to determine the continuity of a function in a given interval? i have already tried a few things with sympy, but i was only able to determine the continuity in a single point. Does anyone have experience with my problem and know a solution?

As an example:

```
x = sp.symbols('x')
f = x**3/x - 1/(x**2-4)
a = -10
b = 10
```

a method should now check whether f is continuous in the interval [a,b]. so in this example `false` should be the output

Comment: You're going to have to give more details. Please provide an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know whether a function is continuous with sympy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881078/how-to-know-whether-a-function-is-continuous-with-sympy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look to see if the result of `continuous_domain` is the domain of interest (or a union of intervals from which the singularities have been removed)

```py
def continuous(eq, x, a, b):
    from sympy.calculus.util import continuous_domain
    from sympy import Interval
    return continuous_domain(eq, x, Interval(a, b)).is_Interval
```

You could also see if there are any singularities in the domain

```py
from sympy.calculus.util import singularities
from sympy.abc import x
>>> singularities(x**2 - 1/(x**2 - 4), x)
{-2, 2}
>>> _ & Interval(-10,10)
{-2, 2}
>>> _.is_empty
False
```

Since the intersection between the domain and the singularities is not empty you know the function is not continuous.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is good but I just want to add that there is a specific technique that can be used for the particular function you have shown. Your example is a rational function with rational coefficients. I don't know if that will always be the case for the functions that you are interested in but if it is then there is a general method that could be used:

```
In [32]: from sympy import *

In [33]: from sympy.abc import x

In [34]: f = x**3/x - 1/(x**2-4)

In [35]: f
Out[35]: 
 2     1   
x  - ──────
      2    
     x  - 4

In [36]: cancel(f)
Out[36]: 
 4      2    
x  - 4⋅x  - 1
─────────────
     2       
    x  - 4   

In [37]: denom(cancel(f))
Out[37]: 
 2    
x  - 4

In [38]: count_roots(denom(cancel(f)), -10, 10)
Out[38]: 2

In [39]: count_roots(denom(cancel(f)), -10, 10) == 0
Out[39]: False
```

This method should guaranteed to find all roots of the denominator for any arbitrarily complicated rational function with rational coefficients. I used `cancel` to remove removable singularities since I presume that you want to consider the function as continuous at those points. Use `f.as_numer_denom()[1]` instead if you want to find zeros of the denominator without cancellation.

Comment: In this answer there is good discussion about the type of singularities that you might encounter and a lower-level query to see if there are discontinuities.